# Access different branches during a git merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

I know you can see the state of a file during a merge conflict using

```
git show :1:file
git show :2:file
git show :3:file
```

But what I want to do a diff ? `git diff :1 :2` doesn't recognise those branches.
Is there a git command to do that (of course I can save `:1:file` locally and do the diff manually.

Also, I can't find any reference to this `show :1:file` in the doc ?

Comment: The `:1:file` syntax was news to me too. In [`gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) look for *stage number*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the unix [`diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) command and a couple of temporary named pipes with the `<(...)` syntax (as [described in this article](https://crashingdaily.wordpress.com/2008/03/06/diff-two-stdout-streams/)):

```
diff    <(git show :1:file) <(git show :2:file)
vimdiff <(git show :1:file) <(git show :2:file)
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `diff` but does with `vimdiff` which is better ;-)

Comment: @mb14 ok, I have aded the vimdiff command in the answer for more visibility.